# Airflow manually run DAG with ExternalTaskSensor

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have DAG with `ExternalTaskSensor` in it. I correctly set `execution_delta` and all work perfectly unless I want to run that DAG manually. My `ExternalTaskSensor` has state running and after `timeout` interval it's failed with exception *airflow.exceptions.AirflowSensorTimeout: Snap. Time is OUT*.

I know way to run it - after manually triggered DAG set every `ExternalTaskSensor` in DAG to state `success` in web interface.

But is the better way to run it manually without to set every `ExternalTaskSensor` in DAG to `success` ?